# What criteria determine a low quality post in the review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queue

[This answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/24415/7590) appeared in the Low Quality Posts review queue because of it's "length and content", according to the description of the queue. Since the answer was quite long, I assume that length wasn't the factor. I understand that the heuristic may not be public, but can anyone shed some light on this?

Was this a consequence of the migration, the rapid accumulation of downvotes, or some key phrase in the answer? I presume it wasn't a [review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143380).

Comment: I'm guessing, but I think it's likely the downvotes.

Comment: It looks like someone flagged it for being of low quality. The interface is anything but clear on what is actually going on.

Comment: @GeorgeMarian That possibility didn't occur to me, but since closure flags are funneled into the review queues, it makes sense that other flags would be as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quality related flags heavily influence this, and the post had one quality related flag which was deemed helpful by a moderator, and the collection of down votes. While we do run quality metrics on questions and answers, we normally don't raise automatic concern unless a post is excessively long, or too short.

That wasn't an audit, but could very well become one in the future - the quality related signal is what we use to find those, and [why mods are so particular when it comes to validating them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160754/why-are-the-moderators-being-so-strict-with-quality-related-flags-recently).